# Mysql Stored Function Performance Issue

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I have a query which runs very fast as itself, but when I use that query as a function's body it suffers a great slowdown.
Here is my test case:

```
/******************* my function definition *********************/
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `GetNextScheduleForProgram`(
  prog_id varchar(10)
) RETURNS varchar(10) CHARSET latin5
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

  DECLARE scheduleid varchar(10);
  SET scheduleid =
  (
      SELECT sc.ScheduleID
        FROM Schedule sc
       WHERE sc.ProgramID=prog_id
         AND sc.StartDate BETWEEN now() and date_add(now(), interval 3 day)
    ORDER BY sc.StartDate ASC
       LIMIT 1

  );
  RETURN scheduleid;

END
```

And here are query statements;

- first, the query runs as itself
- then the function is used with the same parameter:

```
SET @id1 = (SELECT sc.ScheduleID
              FROM Schedule sc
             WHERE sc.ProgramID='23860'
               AND sc.StartDate BETWEEN now() and date_add(now(), interval 3 day)
          ORDER BY sc.StartDate ASC
             LIMIT 1);
SET @id2 = GetNextScheduleForProgram('23860');
```

In this test,  **@id1 is set roughly in 0.03 seconds** while **@id2 arrives in 3.5 seconds** (2 seconds at best). I wonder what causes this remarkable performance hit.

I need to use this function in another stored procedure, thus waiting 2-3 seconds for each row in the stored procedure kills my total performance.

Can anybody help me improve from this point?

Comment: How can a function that uses `now()` be deterministic?

Comment: @newtover: because query timestamps are logged in the binary log

Comment: @Abdullah Battal: could you include the SHOW CREATE TABLE results for the Schedule table, and maybe even pastebin some example data in INSERT queries for testing?

Comment: What does explain say? How it performs the query when tell `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ....` ?

Comment: Does this function *always* return the same result for a given prog_id? If not, it is not deterministic. Mis-declaring it can cause issues with the results and performance.

Comment: @newtover and John Watson: Yes, the function isn't actually deterministic, I must have forget that keyword there while trying stuff and then copy-pasting. Nevertheless it doesn't change much in terms of performance, I can say.

Comment: @Pentium10; explain says;
`1, SIMPLE, sc, ref, progidIndex, progidIndex, 13, const, 292, Using where; Using filesort` 
...
The (bare) query with `SQL_NO_CACHE` run fast as well. But I couldn't embed it into the stored function, it complained that _"there was an error parsing the DDL"_

Comment: @TehShrike; I've put the create table script on https://gist.github.com/959d6220c4135e656a11

Answer (score 1):

Without access to a good set of test data, it's hard to play around with this much.  I have only a few suggestions (*cough*guesses*cough*) for things you could try changing.

### Explicitly declare character type for the function parameter

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `GetNextScheduleForProgram`(
  prog_id varchar(10) CHARSET latin5
...
```

### Just return the subquery in the function

```
BEGIN
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE sc.ScheduleID
    FROM Schedule AS sc
    WHERE sc.ProgramID = prog_id
      AND sc.StartDate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
    ORDER BY sc.StartDate ASC
    LIMIT 1
  );
END
```

### For accurate testing, use SQL_NO_CACHE

I was able to create the function with the above code, and it worked fine under MySQL 5.1.45.  For accurate testing, your queries need this line, or you can't really trust the numbers you get back to find out how expensive your queries are.

### Sacrifice a chicken to the RDBMS deities

That's all I've got for now - I'm curious about this issue, so if you'd be willing to paste some testing data somewhere so that I could experiment more, I'd be willing to do so.

Feel free to ping me in the [MySQL chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql) if you want to chew the fat about this funky-sounding problem.